# Ionic Cordova IOS Livereload Failed to load webpage with error: Could not connect to the server

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

So, I get the error "Failed to load webpage with error: Could not connect to the server" when I try to livereload my app on iOS. I have tried everything I can find on the topic. I've spent all day trying things. So I realized that maybe there is something needed that I don't understand. Here are the things I tried: "ionic cordova prepare iOS", "ionic cordova build iOS", "ionic cordova run ios --address=0.0.0.0 --debug --consolelogs -l", "

```
<allow-navigation href="http://localhost:8080/*" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
```

", "cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview".

I thought maybe someone might have a different idea, or questions that will lead to the solution.

The app opens, and I get that message as an alert on my splash screen, but then it never moves past the splash screen.

Something I just thought of, if I use "ionic cordova run ios --address=0.0.0.0 --debug --consolelogs -l", do I need to use the ip address of my computer?

Any other suggestions or questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-run) will help you here.

Firstly, you will need to run the server.
Do this by running

```
ionic serve
```

This should give you something like this at the end:

```
App running at:
- Local:   http://localhost:8100/ 
- Network: http://192.168.x.xxx:8100/
```

If you are wanting to run this on an actual iOS device on your network, then you will need to use your servers ip address. eg. 192.168.x.xxx.

Then you should be able to run the cordova livereload like this:

```
ionic cordova run ios --livereload-url=http://192.168.x.xxx:8100
```

Hopefully that works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think it worked :P Or I'm a step closer! It now says "Failed to load webpage with error: The request timed out" :P But thanks for the help!!!!!

Comment: a couple of things to check, did you actually put your network ip address, not with the x.xxx but with your numbers? Did you run `ionic serve` to start the server? Can you connect to your dev machine server via the browser on another network device? Also, you can debug in safari and see what the error may be.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the testing iOS device is **connected to WiFi**.

Sometime this error may occur if the device you are trying to run the app on is not connected to the same WiFi network as the development machine you are using.